# Array not reassigning after change

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contains elements my goal is to slice some of the elements inside the array, then later I want to reassign the original array with a new array which is a sublist of the original array but it seems like I can't make that happen please help.

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

function subList(arr){
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
       let res = arr.slice(0,i)
       if(i === 3){
           arr = res;
        }
    }
      
   }
   subList(arr)

   console.log(arr)
   // expected output [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Well, for one thing `slice` is trying to use `I` when maybe it should be using `i`. But without knowing what your output is meant to be it's tough to tell what the code is meant to be doing.

Comment: assigning `arr = res` inside the function doesn't change `let arr` content

Comment: that was a typo but still wont work.

Comment: @Aliayub I'm guessing what your trying to do is arr.splice(i, arr.length - 1) `i` the the index of item you wanna cut off

Comment: The reason the assignment isn't working is because your parameter is named the same as your variable in the outer scope, so you're assigning to your parameter and not to the variable.

Comment: Brave you have a point, show how is done please thank you.

Comment: What output are you expecting? Please add that to your question. The fact that you have a typo means you have not debugged this at all.

Comment: some please show how it's done with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do it.

**Why it isn't working for you:**

You are passing the `arr` into the variable and since it is an object ideally any change you make to it should be reflected outside. But you aren't actually mutating/changing anything in your passed argument, you are reassigning it (with `arr=res`). So that will not make any change to the `arr` outside.

If you do something like `.push()`,`.pop()`, which are operations on the array without reassigning it, that should actually change it.

Example modifying your code with operations that actually modify the array instead of replacing it `splice()` , `push`:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

function subList(arr){
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
       let res = arr.slice(0,i)
       
       if(i === 3){
           arr.splice(0,arr.length);
           arr.push(...res);
           break;
        }
    }
      
   }
   subList(arr)

   console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in an index to the function and just `return arr.slice(0, i);`.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

function subList(arr, i) {
  return arr.slice(0, i);
}

console.log(subList(arr, 3));
```

Comment: you might as well just use slice at this point.

Comment: I wanted to keep in line with the original code @StevenB.

Answer (score 0):

```
let list = [1,2,3,4,5]
   function subList(arr,n){
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
           if(i === 3){
              let res = arr.slice(0,i)
              list = res;
         } 
     }
   }
   subList(list,0)
   console.log(list)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.